# why 'return' in scrapy print so much times

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

when run the spider in command line ,it returns repeatly so much time. When I add a code 'items['i is '] = i' before 'items.append(item)',the result is the last number, and repeated the same time.

So it's maybe the problem with use of return . what's the right one?

```html
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from a.items import Item
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import scrapy
import json

class ASpider(scrapy.Spider):
 name = "A"
 allowed_domains = ["a.com"]
 start_urls = []
 start_urls.append("a.com")
 def parse(self, response):
  jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
  items = []
  item = aItem()
  item['a_id'] = response.url[120:-51]
  item['a_nights'] = jsonresponse['calendar_months'][0]['condition_ranges'][0]['conditions']['min_nights']
  for i in range(0,len(jsonresponse['calendar_months'][0]['days'])):
   item['{}'.format(jsonresponse['calendar_months'][0]['days'][i]['date'])] = jsonresponse['calendar_months'][0]['days'][i]['available']
   items.append(item)
  return items
```

Comment: Could you give more precise examples of what you expect and what you get? I did not understand a bit of your problem.
Also, please embed your code portions in the 'code' tag, so as to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new item for each day.

If you don't you are simply updating that item with each days values and then only the values from the last day remain with a list of items containing multiple references to the same item. Which is exactly what you describe as happening.

```
def parse(self, response):
    jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
    items = []
    for day in jsonresponse['calendar_months'][0]['days']:
        item = Item()
        item['a_id'] = response.url[120:-51]
        item['a_nights'] = jsonresponse['calendar_months'][0]['condition_ranges'][0]['conditions']['min_nights']
        item['{}'.format(day['date'])] = day['available']
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

Consider using the `for` loop above and not indexing when possible.

Comment: now it scraped the same url with the same times like above . In other words, one date one time. But the url returns the data of all date such as day 1 - day 30. So how to scrape or return all the data one time ?